# how to search a string for a date after 3 letters and determine if it falls into a date range

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to write *VBA* for the first time in many years and I am having trouble getting started.

I am creating a form that users will fill out. There is no data until the user fills in the two columns. They will enter information first in column A and then in column B.

Then in each cell they can enter ABC followed by a date or XYZ followed by a date

**I am trying write code that will do the following:**

- When a cell in column B is changed, I want to check to see if it contains the string "ABC" followed by a date (i.e. "ABC7/29/14" or "ABC 7/29/14").
- Where the date format is inconsistent (i.e. sometimes it would be 07/29/2014, sometimes 7/29/14).
- If the cell does contain ABC followed by a date, I want to check if that date falls within a specified date range (ie. 07/29/14 to 7/30/14). This date range will be hardcoded in.
- If the date does fall within that range then I want to check the cell in the same row to the left (column A) to see if it contains the same string "ABC" followed by a date range.
- If the second cell does contain ABC followed by a date I want to check if that date falls within a second specified date range (i.e. "ABC10/12/14" or "ABC 10/13/14").
- If all these conditions are met I want to have a message box pop up.

Thank you so much in advance. I have written a few things for this and I am just not getting good results or even things that run correctly every time.

---

****EDIT****
I have updated my code to what I am currently working with. I am getting a compile Error: Object Required and it is highlighting my Set FirstPmtLDate line. Also the code is running as soon as any cell is changed. I really only want it to run when cells in B column are selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim SecondPmt As Range
Dim FirstPmt As Range
Dim FirstPmtLDate As Date
Dim FirstPmtUDate As Date
Dim SecondPmtLDate As Date
Dim SecondPmtUDate As Date

Set SecondPmt = ActiveCell
Set FirstPmtLDate = DateValue(7 / 29 / 2014)
Set FirstPmtUDate = DateValue(7 / 30 / 2014)
Set SecondPmtLDate = DateValue(10 / 12 / 2014)
Set SecondPmtUDate = DateValue(10 / 13 / 2014)

Application.EnableEvents = False

'If target cell is empty post change, nothing will happen
If IsEmpty(Target) Then
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
End If

'Using If Not statement with the Intersect Method to determine if Target 
'cell is within specified range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B16")) Is Nothing Then
  'Checks if cell contains ABC in any case
  If InStr(SecondPmt.Value, "ABC", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
      'Remove any spaces user may entered
      SecondPmt = Replace(SecondPmt, " ", "")
      'Finds date after ABC in any format
      SecondPmt = Mid(SecondPmt, 4)
      'Checks if it is 07/29/14 or 7/30/14
      SecondPmtDate = DateValue(SecondPmt)
          If SecondPmtDate = SecondPmtLDate Or SecondPmtDate = SecondPmtUDate Then
              'Then if it does have one of those dates the cell to the left is selected
              FirstPmt = SecondPmt.Offset(0, -1)
              'Checks if new cell contains ABC in any case
                  If InStr(FirstPmt.Value, "ABC", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                      'Remove any spaces user may entered
                      FirstPmt = Replace(FirstPmt, " ", "")
                      'Finds date after ABC in any format
                      FirstPmt = Mid(FirstPmt, 4)
                      'Checks if it is 10/12/14 or 10/13/14
                      FirstPmtDate = DateValue(FirstPmt)
                  If FirstPmtDate = FirstPmtLDate Or FirstPmtDate = FirstPmtUDate Then
                      'Then if it does have one of those dates Pop up message box
                      MsgBox "This is not a valid entry!"
                  End If
                  End If
            End If
    End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If InStr(s, "ABC") <> 0 Then
    s = Mid(s, 4)
    d = DateValue(s)
    ....
End If
```

where s is the string from your cell. Don't mind the spaces and additional zeros. The `DateValue` function will do it. Just check if the regional settings on your computer and in Excel are appropriate for the date format you want to use. (see the [documentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that and I think it is the right thing to do. I finished my code and now I am getting an error. I am going to edit my original post to show my new code.

Comment: You have to write `FirstPmtLDate = DateValue("7 / 29 / 2014")`. First you have to use quotes as DateValue expects a string. Second `Date` is not an object type so you don't have to use 'Set'.

Comment: Thank you! I will make these changes and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry about the presence or not of leading zeroes in your date, the Format() function will manage that for you

```
dim strDate as string
dim strDateStart as string
dim strDateEnd as string

dim dtDate as date
dim dtStart as date
dim dtEnd as date

strDateStart = "07/29/2014"
strDateEnd = "07/30/2014"

 ' assuming your in the US and the locale date format of your system is mm/dd/aaaa as this is on what Cdate will operate on  
 ' convert stribgs to dates
 dtStart = Cdate(strDateStart)
 dtEnd = Cdate(strDateEnd)

'assuming that FirstPmt contains ABCdateinanyformat
' we extract the date part (remove ABC) and we format the date
strDate = (Format( left(FirstPmt.value,4),"mm/dd/yyyy")
dtDate = Cdate(strDate)

' you can check if the date is within your range of dates like:


if dtDate >= dtStart) and (dtDate <= dtEnd) then
    ' do your stuff
end if
```